# AutoSuggest Using jquery.tokeninput.js in Repeater Contol in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have taken input textbox in Repeater ItemTemplate and on page load i call a function which fires tokeninput js file

on page load autosuggest works for only first textbox in repeater control .How to make it functional for all textboxes in repeater control.
Any help is much appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using selector by id

```
$("#my-text-input").tokenInput("/url/to/your/script/");
```

use selector by css class

```
$(".myclass").tokenInput("/url/to/your/script/");
```

and assign it to all required texboxes using

CssClass="myclass"